# How to get data from SOAP response in android?

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, soap

What I am trying to do is create a simple Web Service in ASP.NET and get Data from MSSQL server through that web service and use that data in my android application. As a novice, I have tried out this [Helpful](http://adrianandroid.blogspot.in/2012/05/access-c-net-web-service-in.html) link to follow. I have used the same architecture as this tutorial suggest. But getting error in parsing the result (Soap Response) in my result. It is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <soap:Envelope
> xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
> xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
> <soap:Body><findContactResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" />
> </soap:Body> </soap:Envelope>
```

and the GetPropertyCount() method is returning 0, on the other hand, arrayindexoutofBound error is coming up with index 0.

Here is my activity code. Where I have implemented async task for easy handling.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/findContact";

    private static final String OPERATION_NAME = "findContact";// your webservice web method name

    private static final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

    private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://10.0.2.2:58497/WebService/Service.asmx?wsdl";//"http://127.0.0.1:58497/WebService/Service.asmx";

    protected static final String TAG = null;

    TextView tvData1;
    EditText edata;
    Button button;
    String studentNo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tvData1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        edata =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                    studentNo=edata.getText().toString();
                    new Submit().execute(studentNo);
            }
        });
    }

    private class Submit extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... arg) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = new PropertyInfo();
            propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            propertyInfo.name = "eid";

            Log.e("studentNo", studentNo);
            request.addProperty(propertyInfo);
            request.addProperty("eid", studentNo);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
            httpTransport.debug = true;
            try  { 

                    httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                    Log.e("Dump", httpTransport.responseDump.toString());
                SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
                if(result!= null){

                    Log.e("response", result.toString());
                    //To get the data.
                    System.out.println("********Count : "+ result.getPropertyCount());
                    String resultData=result.getProperty(0).toString();
                    Log.e("Found", resultData);
                }
                else{

                    Log.e("Obj", result.toString());
                }
            }  
            catch (Exception exception)   {

                Log.e("Not Found", exception.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
}
```

Now can anyone just show me what went wrong for me? Or how can I get my response without exception? After debugging I came up with this line which is creating exceptions.

```
String resultData=result.getProperty(0).toString();
```

Thanks is advance for any kind of help.

Comment: http://programmingjungle.blogspot.com/2013/05/soap-client-on-android-using-jibx.html?m=1 they are either bonkers or have found a simple approach for soap on Android

Comment: It doesn't help me much. I am looking for what to do in case of araayindexOutofBound error in case of data parsing? Or what do I need to do to get the data parsed from Soap Response @Anthony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

It was in adding property. And slightly changing the response parsing.

Here is the complete code which worked out for me.

Hope it helps others.

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/findContact";

    private static final String OPERATION_NAME = "findContact";// your webservice web method name

    private static final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

    private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://10.0.2.2:58497/WebService/Service.asmx";

    protected static final String TAG = null;
    private static String fahren;

    TextView tvData1;
    EditText edata;
    Button button;
    String studentNo;
    String state;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tvData1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        edata =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                studentNo=edata.getText().toString();
                new Submit().execute(studentNo);
            }
        });
    }

    private class Submit extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = new PropertyInfo();
            propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            propertyInfo.name = "eid";
            propertyInfo.setValue(studentNo);
            request.addProperty(propertyInfo);//problem was here

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
            httpTransport.debug = true;
            try{ 
                httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                Log.e("RequestDump", httpTransport.requestDump.toString());
                Log.e("ResponseDump", httpTransport.responseDump.toString());

                SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
                if(result!= null){
                    state = result.getProperty(0).toString();
                    Log.e("Found", state);
                }
                else{
                    Log.e("Obj", result.toString());
                }
            }  
            catch (Exception exception)   {
                Log.e("Exception", exception.toString());
            }
            return state;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            tvData1.setText(result);
        }
    }
}
```

I have implemented an async task as well to get rid of run time exceptions on Main thread. Need to add the request.addProperty(propertyInfo) properly.